# google-compute-engine redundancy how does it handle equipment failure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

what happens to my virtual instance in the case of a hardware failure of the google compute-engine?
Does the compute-engine auto migrate like it does when maintenance is performed?

Answer (score 3):

Google states that in case of hardware failure, your VM will also be [migrated if possible, or restarted on a new host](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) if migration is not possible.

> Live migration keeps your instances running during:
>
> - Failed hardware such as memory, CPU, network interface cards, disks, power, and so on. This is done on a best-effort basis; if a hardware fails completely or otherwise prevents live migration, the VM crashes and restarts automatically and a [`hostError`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror) is logged.

Comment: The only exception is preemptible instances -  "Preemptible instances cannot live migrate to a regular VM instance, or be set to automatically restart when there is a maintenance event."